Custom job error on Flink using Flink Kubernetes Operator
I need an advice how to debug, what can I check on falling flink job.
I have installed Flink Kubernetes Operator v1.8 ok K8s, created job from template "statemachine.jar" and it runs successful.
I have created new docker image with custom jar (dev team application) and during pod startup I'm receiving errors as follow:
ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Fatal error occurred in the cluster entrypoint.
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationExecutionException: Could not execute application.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.runApplicationEntryPoint(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:337) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.lambda$runApplicationAsync$2(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:254) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.pekko.ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$withContextClassLoader$0(ClassLoadingUtils.java:41) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:59) [flink-rpc-akka109c04d3-d759-4da9-a716-b702329308fe.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$PekkoForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:57) [flink-rpc-akka109c04d3-d759-4da9-a716-b702329308fe.jar:1.18.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationExecutionException: Could not execute application.
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: unknown protocol: local
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:105) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.runApplicationEntryPoint(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:301) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: local
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.configuration.ConfigUtils.decodeListFromConfig(ConfigUtils.java:133) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.ExecutionConfigAccessor.getJars(ExecutionConfigAccessor.java:77) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.executors.PipelineExecutorUtils.getJobGraph(PipelineExecutorUtils.java:77) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.executors.EmbeddedExecutor.submitAndGetJobClientFuture(EmbeddedExecutor.java:123) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.executors.EmbeddedExecutor.execute(EmbeddedExecutor.java:104) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2238) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamContextEnvironment.java:189) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:118) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2099) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at com.app.Application$.main(Application.scala:50) ~[?:?]
    at com.app.Application.main(Application.scala) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:105) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.runApplicationEntryPoint(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:301) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ... 13 more

I tried different versions of flink images:
flink:1.19-scala_2.12-java11
flink:1.18.1-scala_2.12-java11
flink:1.17.2-scala_2.12-java11
Every time problem is the same.
What can I check and how to get to the source of this error?

You mentioned that you are using a custom image with your jar included in it. Have you made sure to specifically reference that in your FlinkDeployment as your appropriate image (via flinkImage)?
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: ...
spec:
  image: "{{ yourCustomImage }}"
  ...
  flinkConfiguration:

You'll just need to ensure that your base image used in your Dockerfile aligns with the version of Flink that you are intending to target:
# Dockerfile (example targeting 1.18)
FROM .../flink:1.18.1

COPY .../statemachine.jar /opt/flink/jars/statemachine.jar

And then within your deployment that you copy your jar into the appropriate location it was placed in the custom image:
# FlinkDeployment
spec:
  job:
    jarURI: local:///opt/flink/jars/statemachine.jar

If this doesn't work, you might consider posting some additional details about your FlinkDeployment, Dockerfile, etc. If your jobs are targeting the custom image, you could also consider using Docker or executing directly into the pod running the image to explore to ensure your jar file is where you'd expect.

My spec is using proper image and jarURI. Jar file is located in folder 'jarURI: local:///opt/flink/usrlib/myjob.jar'. Jar is starting but i'm getting java exception 'Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: local' and I don't know if this is related with some configuration parameter I'm missing or if this is problem inside jar.

When I tested other versions of flink I've made changes in dockerfile and FlinkDeployment files simultaneously, for example: From dockerfile: 'FROM flink:1.17.2-scala_2.12-java11' and in the FlinkDeployment file: 'flinkVersion: v1_17'.
